# Success block getting executed at last

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am new to jQuery and hit with the below issue. Here is the click handler I have. The issue is, the code in the success block of ajax call is getting executed after the click method finishes.

I highly appreciate your inputs to direct me in fixing this issue. Thanks so much.

```js
$('#back').click(function(e) {
  var isSelected = false;
  var bf = {};

  isSelected = confirm("Do you want to ?");
  if (isSelected == true) {
    self.delegate.getRf(id, id2).success(function(data) {
      bf = data;
    }).error(function(data) {

    });
  }

  //other code that is to be executed
});
```

Comment: The `success` handler is ***supposed*** to be executed after the AJAX request completes, hence it will always occur after any other synchronous code has executed.

Answer (score 0):

This is very common issue. if we are expecting something should done after the ajax request complete. put it in ajax success method or make ajax request asynchronous. 
or you can use deferred promise.

asynchronous request example,

```
$('#back').click(function(e) {
 var isSelected = false;
 var bf = {};
 isSelected = confirm("Do you want to ?");
 if (isSelected == true) {
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     async:false,
     url: "/pages/test/",
     success: function(result) {
      bf = data;// now our bf is available inside a function
    },
    error: function(result) {
    alert('error');
    }
  });
 //do whatever you want to do with bf.
}
```

for deferred promise please visit [this](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/)